# How do i stop the blurring when zooming in on a UIScrollView?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I have been trying to find out how to redraw a view when i have zoomed in on it, i have looked at many examples (mainly native code) but am still struggling to get it fully working.

So let me try and explain what i am attempting....
I have a UIScrollView With a UIView(container) in it this in turn has many views within it each with UITextFields inside, the functionality i am looking for is when a user clicks on any of the view it is zoomed in on and then goes back into place when the user is finished with it which does all actually work fine except for the quality of the zoomed in view is terrible. 
I am using a UIScrollViewDelegate but not really sure what to put in the ZoomedEnded function to handle the redraw, I have tried using the CATiledLayer but am not really sure how this is used and i always just end up with a black screen.
There is not much code to show as

```
svCertScroller.SetZoomScale(2.34f, true);
```

Works fine and in the UIScrollDelegate event ViewForZoomingInScrollView just returns the view i want zoom in on but i don't have anything in ZoomingEnded event at the moment I have tried loads but nothing even seems to get close.
So any help on what to put inside this event to sharpen up the zoomed in view would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the scroll canvas larger and plot the contents at a higher resolution.

Comment: could you be a little bit more specific please? maybe some code and won't making the Scroll canvas larger mess up the scrolling ability?

Comment: Read up a little more on how a scroll view works.  There's a view behind it that can be defined to be larger than the "window", yet shrunk down to fit in the "window".

Comment: Another way to put it:  make your view inside larger than the UIScrollView.  Zoomed in would be at 1.0f, Zoomed out would be at .5f or some other arbitrary value.

Comment: Ok this works now, I have recreated my UI 2x the original size and then shrink the UI on Viewload so it fits on the screen, now when i zoom into any view within the UIScrollView it is not blurred. Thank you both for your help it is much appreciated :)